# Problema con Login de mysql php ajax html con apache cordova

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache-cordova

Estoy haciendo una aplicación basada en web con `cordova`, ya tengo el `splash` y el `frontend` de la aplicación, pero quiero hacer el `login` y que se conecte a la base de datos del servidor.

Para esto tengo un archivo llamado **www/Login.html** tengo dos `input` y jalo su valor por el `id`, al momento de dar clic, hago una función para que me los compare con un `php` que esta alojado en un servidor, los paso por `POST` y que inicie la función cuando le de clic al botón de `login`, pero no paso de la autenticación, se queda trabado.

No me dice errores solo eso **"authenticating"**. Espero y me puedan ayudar. Lo estoy probando un un celular y no en un emulador.

```
<html>Email: <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="" /> <br />
    Password: <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="" /> <br />
    <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
    <button id="registerButton">Register</button>
    <br />
    Message: <p id="status"></p></html>


Email: <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="" /> <br />
    Password: <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="" /> <br />
    <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
    <button id="registerButton">Register</button>
    <br />
    Message: <p id="status"></p>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "https://get-data.php";

            $("#loginButton").click(function () {
                var email = $.trim($("#email").val());
                var password = $.trim($("#password").val());

                $("#status").text("Authenticating...");
                var loginString = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&login=";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", crossDomain: true, cache: false,
                    url: url,
                    data: loginString,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "success") {
                            $("#status").text("Login Success..!");
                            localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
                            window.location.href = "Portal.html";
                        }
                        else if (data == "error") {
                            $("#status").text("Login Failed..!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("","","","") or die("connection error");
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {   
        $register = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email'"));
        if($register == 0)
        {
            $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`password`) VALUES ('$email','$password')");
            if($insert)
                echo "success";
            else
                echo "error";
        }
        else if($register != 0)
            echo "exist";
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='$password'"));
        if($login != 0)
            echo "success";
        else
            echo "error";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Haz un `console.log(data)` dentro de la función del `success` en ajax, y muestranos lo que imprime

Comment: De la misma forma que haces el success, agrega otra función llamada `error: function(fail)` y con console.log revisa que error arroja

Comment: Gracias @DaxTter77

Comment: Gracias DaxTter77 Jonathan Orta lo hice y me dio un error de conexion volvi a revisar mi archivo php del servidor y era algo tan tonto como un campo que no coincidia con la base de datos entonces ya hice que funcione de todas maneras por si a alguien le sirve dejo el codigo corregido